# Is it possible to paperclip:refresh just a particular type of thumb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

My photo model has a few different versions, and I only updated the `tiny_thumb`. Can I just refresh that one type rather than all the other types as well?

A clip from my model:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :photo, 
      :styles => { :cropped_thumb => {:geometry => "115x70#", :jcrop => true}, :resized_thumb => {:geometry => "115x70>"}, :deal => {:geometry => "64x56#"},  
      :cropped_large => {:geometry => "#{PHOTO_IMAGE_WIDTH}x#{PHOTO_IMAGE_HEIGHT}#", :jcrop => true},
      :resized_large => {:geometry => "#{PHOTO_IMAGE_WIDTH}x#{PHOTO_IMAGE_HEIGHT}>"},
      :tiny_thumb => {:geometry => '120x120>'},
```

I tried this..

```
rake paperclip:refresh:tiny_thumb class=Photo
```

But I think it was a poor guess and didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried but you can do this in your ruby script:

```
Photo.all.each{ |instance| instance.photo.reprocess!(:tiny_thumb) }
```

Comment: Great idea.. but it returns this `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
 from (irb):5:in `reprocess!'
 from (irb):5`

Comment: odd, this should be merged, see here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/pull/427 what version are you using?

Comment: Worked! I was using 2.3.4.. Upgraded to 2.3.10 which was just enough for Rails 2 to understand it and run this feature. Thanks so much!!!